# pthread is slower than the "default" version

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

## SITUATION

I want to see the advantage of using `pthread`. If I'm not wrong: threads allow me to execute given parts of program in parallel.

so here is what I try to accomplish: I want to make a program that takes a number(let's say `n`) and outputs the sum of `[0..n]`.

*code*

```c
#define MAX 1000000000

int
main() {
    long long n = 0;
    for (long long i = 1; i < MAX; ++i)
        n += i;

    printf("\nn: %lld\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

> time: 0m2.723s

to my understanding I could simply take that number `MAX` and divide by `2` and let 2 `threads`
do the job.

*code*

```c
#define MAX          1000000000
#define MAX_THREADS  2
#define STRIDE       MAX / MAX_THREADS

typedef struct {
    long long off;
    long long res;
} arg_t;

void*
callback(void *args) {
    arg_t *arg = (arg_t*)args;

    for (long long i = arg->off; i < arg->off + STRIDE; ++i)
        arg->res += i;

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int
main() {
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    arg_t     results[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
        results[i].off = i * STRIDE;
        results[i].res = 0;

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, callback, (void*)&results[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    long long result;
    result = results[0].res;

    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i)
        result += results[i].res;

    printf("\nn: %lld\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

> time: 0m8.530s

## PROBLEM

The version with `pthread` runs slower. Logically this version should run faster, but maybe creation of threads is more expensive.

Can someone suggest a solution or show what I'm doing/understanding wrong here?

Comment: A decent compiler could even be able to optimize the first loop into a single assignment.

Comment: And always remember to do benchmarking on optimized builds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you recommend a profiler for C (OS: linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is cache thrashing combined with a lack of optimization (I bet you're compiling without it on).

The naive (-O0) code for

```
for (long long i = arg->off; i < arg->off + STRIDE; ++i)
    arg->res += i;
```

will access the memory of `*arg`. With your `results` array being defined the way it is, that memory is very close to the memory of the next arg and the two threads will fight for the same cache-line, making RAM caching very ineffective.

If you compile with -O1, the loop should use a register instead and only write to memory at the end. Then, you should get better performance with threads (higher optimization levels on gcc seem to optimize  the loop out completely)

Another (better) option is to align `arg_t` on a cache line:

```
typedef struct {
    _Alignas(64) /*typical cache line size*/ long long off;
    long long res;
} arg_t;
```

Then you should get better performance with threads regardless of whether or not you turn optimization on.

Good cache utilization is generally very important in multithreaded programming (and Ulrich Drepper has much to say on that topic in his infamous [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Elstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried the optimization flags... and yeah they run significantly faster, BUT the second version stays a bit slower than the first version.

Comment: @Hrant Here's my testing/benchmarking script (clobbers thr.c and a.out in the current directory): https://pastebin.com/f8C9B1Hr . I'm getting results consistent with what I've written in my  answer.

Comment: @Hrant Careful if you use the `time` binary rather than the bash builtin. The binary defaults to reporting user-time first (sum of all user times on all CPU cores). Elapsed time is third.

Comment: Ah, that's great to know, thank you for your time invested here.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a whole bunch of threads is very unlikely to be quicker than simply adding numbers. The CPU can add an awfully large number of integers in the time it takes the kernel to set up and tear down a thread. To see the benefit of multithreading, you really need each thread to be doing a significant task -- significant compared to the overhead in creating the thread, anyway. Alternatively, you need to keep a pool of threads running, and assign them work according to some allocation strategy.

Multi-threading works best when an application consists of tasks that are somewhat independent, that would otherwise be waiting on one another to complete. It isn't a magic way to get more throughput.

Comment: the calculation takes about 3 secs. I guess it isn't significant enough for threads?

Comment: I guess you could do some profiling, and try to work out whether it is or not. On Linux, at least, thread set-up amounts to much the same as process set-up -- it's a fairly heavy undertaking, compared to integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank You for clarification. I'll accept your answer after 10 mins.

Comment: @KevinBoone, if you ignore the cost of creating the threads (ie create a pool at the beginning and reuse it as needed), chances are good that splitting your array in 4 parts and doing the calculation on each part on a separate thread would actually see an improvement in real time length.

Comment: @Hrant Not insignificant. System threads take a bunch of micro seconds to start which is a lot of time for modern CPUs, but that overhead pales in comparison to whole seconds. Used correctly, threads should yield better speeds here.